# Multiple conditions with Select Case in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, case

I am trying to figure out how to test two conditions in a Case Statement.

```
Select Case txtWeight.Text
     Case Is <= 2
        decShippingCost = (decShipping2 + (decShipping2 * 0.26))
     Case Is > 2 and <= 4
        decShippingCost = (decShipping4 + (decShipping4 * 0.026))
```

I cannot get AND to work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select Case txtWeight.Text
    Case Is <= 2
        decShippingCost = (decShipping2 + (decShipping2 * 0.26))
    Case 3 to 4
        decShippingCost = (decShipping4 + (decShipping4 * 0.026))
End Select
```

Or maybe this if you want to catch 2.5 as >2.

```
Select Case txtWeight.Text
    Case Is <= 2
        decShippingCost = (decShipping2 + (decShipping2 * 0.26))
    Case 2.01 to 4
        decShippingCost = (decShipping4 + (decShipping4 * 0.026))
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you!  Its always something silly and small :)  Appreciate your help!

Comment: `Case Is > 2, Is <= 4`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to check for a weight greater than two in the second Case. If it's not greater than two, then it will have entered the first case. So you can simplify it to this:

```
Select Case txtWeight.Text
    Case Is <= 2
        decShippingCost = (decShipping2 + (decShipping2 * 0.26))
    Case Is <= 4
        decShippingCost = (decShipping4 + (decShipping4 * 0.026))
End Select
```

Comment: It is true, but it's a dangerous way to go if someone refactor the first Case IS and dont realise that it will affect the second one. But still, +1 from me because for the information about the possibility to do so.